# MySQL - Ignore WHERE condition if key/value pair doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In a Wordpress order based system I am selecting people going to an event on a certain date and location.

I also need to see if there are any *order notes* existing for any matching orders, which I do by selecting the `meta_value` where the `meta_key ="_wc_acof_2"`.

The problem is when I add the condition to my WHERE clause the code stops returning records where that meta key/value pair doesn't exist (i.e. there are no order notes). Whereas I still need to select those records just return null or similar for the order notes.

The problem line in the WHERE clause is:

```
AND jn_postmeta_guestnotes.meta_key = "_wc_acof_2"
```

In my head I would like to write that line similar to:

```
AND (jn_postmeta_guestnotes.meta_key = "_wc_acof_2" OR 'there is no matching meta_key so just ignore this condition and return the record anyway')
```

The full query:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(" ",wp_postmeta.meta_value,jn_postmeta_lastname.meta_value) AS Name,
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value AS Adults,
    jn_postmeta_guestnotes.meta_value AS Notes
 FROM
    wp_postmeta
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS jn_postmeta_lastname ON wp_postmeta.post_id = jn_postmeta_lastname.post_id
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS jn_postmeta_guestnotes ON wp_postmeta.post_id = jn_postmeta_guestnotes.post_id
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.order_item_id
 WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_first_name"
        AND jn_postmeta_lastname.meta_key = "_billing_last_name"
        AND jn_postmeta_guestnotes.meta_key = "_wc_acof_2"
        AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = "Adults"
        AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.meta_key = "Booking Type"
        AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.meta_value LIKE "%'.$showlocation.'%"
        AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_key = "Booking Date"
        AND (jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_value = "'.$showdateformata.'" OR jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_value = "'.$showdateformatb.'")
        AND wp_posts.post_status = "wc-completed"
 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: Change 'WHERE' to 'AND'. Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, GROUP BY is liable to return misleading results.

Comment: @Strawberry `GROUP BY` without aggreagted function work just as `DISTINCT` but also allow `HAVING`, so not really misleading.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You know that that's not (necessarily) true - especially where the thing being grouped on is not the PK of the source table. See temporary (and, admittedly, contrived) illustration of the point below...

Comment: In this case ID is always unique so I don't think its a problem here, but its an important point to note. Still not sure how to solve the original question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to put the extra bit in a sub-select like so:

```
(SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_wc_acof_2" AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID) AS Notes
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put all filtering condition on the `ON` so the left join work. On the `WHERE` will remove the nulls

```
.....
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date 
    ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.order_item_id
   AND 1 = 1 
   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_billing_first_name" 
   AND jn_postmeta_lastname.meta_key = "_billing_last_name" 
   AND jn_postmeta_guestnotes.meta_key = "_wc_acof_2" 
   AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = "Adults" 
   AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.meta_key = "Booking Type" 
   AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_location.meta_value LIKE "%'.$showlocation.'%" 
   AND jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_key = "Booking Date" 
   AND 
   ( 
     jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_value = "'.$showdateformata.'" 
     OR 
     jn_woocommerce_order_itemmeta_date.meta_value = "'.$showdateformatb.'" 
   ) 
   AND wp_posts.post_status = "wc-completed"
```